# Get sum of qty based on hour window

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I'm working on a problem to figure out how much qty of product was created and dispatched between certain hours. For example, I need to see how much was created (by created I mean how many orders were created with X qty) between 6pm today and 3pm tomorrow. I'm trying to create a time bin for this but whatever I try isn't working out.

```
select CREATE_DATE
    , CREATE_TIME
    , RELEASED_DATE
    , RELEASED_TIME
    , sum(case
        when CREATE_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CREATE_DATE), 0)
            and CREATE_TIME >= '18:00:00' AND CREATE_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0,             CREATE_DATE), 1)
        then ORDER_QTY
        when CREATE_DATE = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, CREATE_DATE), 1)
            and CREATE_TIME <= '14:59:59'
        then ORDER_QTY
        end) as small_window_qty
    , sum(ORDER_QTY) as ord_qty
    , sum(RELEASED_QTY) as rls_qty
from table
```

Any help with this would be appreciated. Just need a way to organize the days into the following buckets: Normal Hour Window = Created 6pm to 6pm;  Smaller Hour Window = Created 6pm to 3pm; Agreed Upon = Dispatch by 3pm (12am to 3pm)

Edit: Some clarification. What im trying to accomplish is a root cause analysis. We have orders that create every day, and must ship within 2 days of being created. We're trying to figure out why our orders are not shipping on time. So as an RCA, Im trying to dig into the orders, when they were created, when they were dispatched(or released, same thing) and when they shipped. The Hour Window's mentioned above are cutoff times for orders to be created for a certain day. Example:

300 units were created today, and they must ship 2 days from now. I want to see, of that 300 created, how many were created before 3pm, and of that, how much dispatched by 3pm same day. Hope that clarifies things. Not everything that is created must be dispatched the same day, as we have 2 days to ship the orders.

Comment: It would be most helpful to show some sample data spread out over 2 days (at least) that touch all the possible windows and show which rows fall into which windows. Your last window is a little concerning because it refers to "dispatch" and not "created". It would help to clarify how you know something is "dispatched by ...".

Comment: Also, it's usually helpful to see the table definition, including column names / types, in case you have a conversion issue.

Comment: conversion is not the issue, just having trouble creating the correct expression here. I should clarify, dispatch = Release, same thing.

Comment: @SMor i've added results to the original post

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Be specific about what isn't working for you.  Your current SQL is not valid.  You don't seem to be asking about the actual SQL error.  Can you provide actual test data, the actual SQL, the actual results and expected results, based on that data?

Comment: CREATE_DATE CREATE_TIME RELEASED_DATE RELEASED_TIME Small Window Qty Order Qty RLS Qty
8/11/2021 21:33:00 8/13/2021 9:33:45 2 2 2
8/12/2021 18:27:00 8/13/2021 7:02:36 4 4 4
8/15/2021 4:27:00 8/15/2021 6:33:44 NULL 150 150
8/12/2021 17:57:00 8/12/2021 21:50:44 NULL 115 115
8/10/2021 7:57:00 8/11/2021 19:46:44 NULL 13 13
8/12/2021 11:28:00 8/12/2021 13:53:16 NULL 27 27
8/10/2021 21:34:00 8/11/2021 22:08:17 952 952 952
8/13/2021 9:27:00 8/13/2021 10:51:33 NULL 272 272
8/11/2021 7:27:00 8/12/2021 17:20:28 NULL 8 8
8/15/2021 7:45:00 8/16/2021 0:01:17 NULL 1 1

Comment: I've added the results here^. its messy here, but copy pasting it to a workbook should help. I know the SQL code is invalid, there is no error, but I'm not getting the right results. Currently, the dates and times go by a 24 hour period (the normal), what I'm trying to accomplish is to look at it from a different lens. I want to look at the day as starting at 6pm, and ending at 3pm, then another that starts at 6pm, ends at 5:59pm, etc. Hope that was clear.

Comment: Please [edit] any clarifications directly into the question, where you can format it, rather than making us try and decipher comments.

Comment: @DaleK I never really got the answer I was looking for, so that's why. But I went back and marked each answer now.

Comment: @DaleK I tried posting the query results in the original post, but it kept bringing it as a picture, rather than text. I posted as text earlier and you said I'm not supposed to so I did what worked.

Answer (score 1):

you're leaving a lot of info out so i'm filling in the blanks and making assumptions here. doublecheck that my data types line up with your data types.

```
create table sales (create_date date, create_time time, released_date date, released_time time, qty int)

insert sales
select '1/14/13','18:45','1/15/13','10:45', 10
union all
select '1/14/13','19:45','1/15/13','12:45', 12
union all
select '1/15/13','19:15','1/16/13','16:45', 6
union all
select '1/15/13','18:00','1/16/13','14:45', 25
union all
select '1/15/13','18:45','1/16/13','15:00', 3
union all
select '1/16/13','19:45','1/17/13','16:30', 1
union all
select '1/16/13','20:45','1/17/13','17:45', 9
union all
select '1/17/13','18:30','1/18/13','18:00', 17
union all
select '1/18/13','18:30','1/19/13','17:15', 15
union all
select '1/18/13','18:45','1/19/13','19:15', 21

with base as
(
select *
, cast(create_date as datetime) + cast(create_time as datetime) as createtime
, cast(released_date as datetime) + cast(released_time as datetime) as releasetime
, datediff(hour,cast(create_date as datetime) + cast(create_time as datetime),cast(released_date as datetime) + cast(released_time as datetime)) as hrs
from sales
),

base2 as
(
select qty
, case
    when create_time >= '18:00' and hrs <= 21 then 'small'
    when create_time >= '18:00' and hrs <= 24 then 'normal'
    else 'outside'
end as orderwindow
, case
    when hrs between 6 and 21 then 'pass'
    else 'fail'
end as agreedupon
from base
)

select sum(qty) as qty, orderwindow, agreedupon
from base2
group by orderwindow, agreedupon

drop table sales
```

this should give you the end result of being able to tell how much was created, what window of time it falls into, and if released by 3pm. adjust as needed.

i didn't want the code to get messy and convoluted so i used 2 CTEs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your answer is quite helpful. I can take that and work to see if I can improve it. I've posted some clarifications above in my original post, hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your expected result and also your input data looks messay and not clear. So I used the data provided by the above answer.  It looks you get running sum. If you can review the answer and get back to me if you need more modifications that is good. I suggest you to edit your Question and be more clear with your sample data and expected answer. Add more details to the question.

```
create table sales (create_date date, create_time time, released_date date, released_time time, qty int)

INSERT INTO  sales
 select '1/14/13','18:45','1/15/13','10:45', 10
 union all
 select '1/14/13','19:45','1/15/13','12:45', 12
 union all
 select '1/15/13','19:15','1/16/13','16:45', 6
 union all
 select '1/15/13','18:00','1/16/13','14:45', 25
 union all
 select '1/15/13','18:45','1/16/13','15:00', 3
 union all
 select '1/16/13','19:45','1/17/13','16:30', 1
 union all
 select '1/16/13','20:45','1/17/13','17:45', 9
 union all
 select '1/17/13','18:30','1/18/13','18:00', 17
 union all
 select '1/18/13','18:30','1/19/13','17:15', 15
 union all
 select '1/18/13','18:45','1/19/13','19:15', 21


 SELECT 
   create_date
  , create_time
  , released_date 
  , released_time
 ,SUM(QTY) OVER ( PARTITION BY  A.[Dispatched Window] ORDER BY  released_date ) AS  [Sum_qty]
 ,Qty
  FROM
   (

  SELECT  
  create_date
 , create_time
 , released_date 
 , released_time
 , CASE WHEN  released_date BETWEEN      CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), create_date, 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '18:00:00.0000000' , 108)) AND    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY,1, create_date), 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '18:00:00.0000000' , 108))   THEN  'Normal Window'
        WHEN  released_date BETWEEN      CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), create_date, 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '17:59:00.0000000' , 108)) AND    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(DAY,1, create_date), 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '15:00:00.0000000' , 108))   THEN  'Smaller Window'
        WHEN  released_date BETWEEN      CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), create_date, 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '00:00:00.0000000' , 108)) AND    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(CHAR(8), create_date, 112)   + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), '15:00:00.0000000' , 108))   THEN  'Aggreed AUpon'
     ELSE 'N/A'
   END AS  [Dispatched Window]
  , Qty
 FROM dbo.sales
) AS A
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @silverwing90 Can you check this answer and get back to me with your sample data and Expected output it will be great

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it's not quite what I needed though. I posted some clarifications above in my original post. hope that clarifies enough

Comment: I checked your details but I have one concenr as If you can add some data script sample and expected output as a image, I can help a little.  Because your query is not really clear. That is y some one has disgrated your question. I am trying to help you. But I need the mentioned details. Thanks @silverwing90